# Url.Action does not send route parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I want my url be like:

```
localhost:22504/Apps/App/{name}/{id}/{type}
```

So I added route values to Global.asax file:

```
routes.Add("AppRoute", new MyRoute("App/{name}/{id}/{type}", new { controller = "Apps", action = "App" }));
routes.Add("AppRoute2", new MyRoute("App/{id}/{type}", new { controller = "Apps", action = "App" }));
```

Those routes placed above Default route which looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

And my controllers:

```
public ActionResult App(string id, string name, string type)
{
    //code here
}
```

My Url.Action:

```
href="@Url.Action("App", "Apps", new { id = GuidEncoder.Encode(app.AppID), name = "Read more", type = "review"})
```

Url.Action renders as:

```
href="/Apps/App/lBF8BPwVykebNe9XU1KOOg?name=21webmerce-manager1"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try using Url.RouteUrl ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460200(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: This article can be useful also http://www.patridgedev.com/2011/08/22/subtleties-with-using-url-routeurl-to-get-fully-qualified-urls/

Comment: i did not, will try now) thanks

Comment: @GekaLlaur it worked for me, thanks a lot)

Turned out it worked and before, but at the end of the day I was looking at another url on page) Now i know 2 ways to do it, thanks!